# Use Dirichlet's theorem to prove that there are infinite primes on a certain arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory

My textbook says that Dirichlet's theorem states that there's at least one prime number in an arithmetic progression whose first element is $a$ and whose constant difference is $r$, provided $a$ and $r$ are positive integers and are coprimes. The exercise basically asks me to prove that there are infinite prime numbers on that sequence, and tells me to use Dirchlet's theorem. Does anyone know how to prove it without using modular congruence? I ask that because modular congruence is only introduced on the next chapter.

Comment: Hint: you could also start the arithmetic progression at a+r, or a+2r, or a+3r, and so on. At the same time, Dirichlet's original theorem, and its usual statement, already assert the infinitude, not just one. Nevertheless, the stronger assertion does follow from the weaker. As in other comments, it would be foolhardy to try to prove this from scratch: just prove the stronger, granting the weaker. (And constant _difference_, not constant _ratio_.)

Comment: Arithmetic progressions have constant difference, not ratio

Comment: On rereading, I think you are asking;  if you know there is one prime in an arbitrary progression (with fixed start and fixed positive distance) prove there are infinitely many.  That's an easy induction, and does not require congreunce.

Comment: What book is it ?

Comment: Dirichlet's Theorem actually proves more than is stated here - that modulo a given $n$ the primes are equidistributed, on average, between the different possible residue classes. It would in fact be really hard to prove the version of the theorem quoted (a single prime in each progression) without proving that there are infinitely many primes in each qualifying progression - I don't know of such a proof. But as an exercise - clearly you have to find a related progression which excludes the prime you have already identified - and it involves a neat piece of logic and deduction.

Comment: @Aryadeva: It's a book that's in Portuguese. It's called "Curso de Álgebra" by prof. Abramo Hefez.

Comment: Thznk you so much Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question here is the passage from "one prime in the progression" to "infinitely many primes".  But that passage is easily accomplished.

Suppose, to the contrary, that there were only finitely primes in the progression $A=\{a+bn\,|\, n\in \mathbb N\}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then let $p$ denote the biggest one.  Then the progression $\{p+b+bn\,|\,n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a sub progression of $A$ and by (the seriously constrained version of) Dirichlet, it must contain at least one prime.  Hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: I think I understand your solution, but I only have one doubt: Is $p+b$ supposed to be a coprime of $b$?

Comment: @PedroCardoso  Of course.  Since $p\in A$ by assumption we know that $p=a+mb$ for some natural number $m$.  Thus $p+b=a+(m+1)b$.  But since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ we must have $a+kb=1$ for any $k\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!